# Type-casting using function call T(0) and templates

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I have a function converting a "simulation domain" into an array of voxels (3D pixels). Each voxel can be 0 or 1, or at least `false` or `true`. 
As the domain can be really big, as the discretisation step can be very small, it requires a very big amount of memory.

I use my array of voxels to perform scattering simulations using FFTW3 (In that case, it's just great if the function can work on an array of `double[2]` (complex type known by FFTW3, so that I can perform in-place transform). But when I use my array of voxels to perform "simple" operations (volume fraction estimation for example) I just want my array to be of the smallest type I can work with, so an array of boolean would be just fine.

I was thinking of something like the following  :

```
#include <iostream>
int N = 10 ;


template<typename T>
void voxelizator(T* & Voxels) {
    // N = total number of voxels, stored in a row-major 1D array
    if (Voxels==NULL) Voxels = new T[N] ; //
    for (int n = 0 ;  n < N ; n++) Voxels[n] = T(0) ;
    { // Code to voxelizate the space -- DUMB condition 
        for (int n = 0 ; n<N ; n++) if (n%2==0) Voxels[n] = T(1) ;
    }
}



int main()
{
    int * voxOfInt = NULL ;
    std::cout << "Array of int :" << std::endl ;
    voxelizator(voxOfInt) ;
    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl ;
    for (int n = 0 ; n < N ; n++)  std::cout << n << "\t" << voxOfInt[n] << std::endl ;
    delete[] voxOfInt ;

    bool * voxOfBool = NULL ;
    std::cout << "Array of boolean " << std::endl ;
    voxelizator(voxOfBool) ;
    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl ;
    for (int n = 0 ; n < N ; n++)  std::cout << n << "\t" << voxOfBool[n] << std::endl ;
    delete[] voxOfBool ;

}
```

but the error `ISO C++ forbids casting to an array type 'double[2]'` is fired when i call this function with an array of double[2] (complex from FFTW3) (or int[2] like in this example : )

```
...    
typedef double complex [2]  ;
...
// in main {}

    complex * voxOfArray = NULL ;
    std::cout << "Array of an array " << std::endl ;
    voxelizator(voxOfArray) ; // It fails to call the T(0) at compile time, but i would be more than happy to explain g++ what is T(0) for int[2] ...
    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl ;
    for (int n = 0 ; n < N ; n++)  std::cout << n << "\t" << voxOfArray[n] << std::endl ;
    delete[] voxOfArray ;
```

The question is : Where can I give g++ the recipie to typecast :

- T(0) into {0,0} and T(1) into {1,0} when T is double[2] ?
- T(0) into FALSE and T(1) into TRUE when T is a boolean ?

Note : 
The function call operator for a type seems weird to me but I know it works fine with the following sign function I already use (Please, insert here the picture of the dog doing some chemistry and saying "I've no idea what I'm doing")

```
template <typename T> int sign(T value) {
    return (T(0) < value) - (value < T(O)) ; 
}
```

Comment: The more descriptive term but still technically wrong is a `constructor call cast`: the `T(whatever)` looks like a call to the constructor of `T`, but of course fundamental types like arrays and `int`s don't have constructors, the C style cast syntax just lends itself to creative code.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how you are trying to call `voxelizator`, a short program that compiles and reproduces the error.

Comment: I don't think you'll get that to work at all if T is an array of `double[2]` (or any other array type) - you can't assign to an array; `voxels[n] = whatever;` is invalid (AFAIK) whatever you try to put on the RHS if `voxels[n]` is an array.

Comment: [Do not use manual memory management.](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/) Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I added something that works, and something that doesn't :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks, but I'm very happy with manual memory management when I deal with n-D row-major array and interoperability with FFTW...

Comment: @Pascail Sorry but you’re doing it wrong. You are making your code more complex, brittle and error-prone and you are flouting best practices.

Comment: +1 onto using proper, modern C++. Don't use `new`. Don't use `delete`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree, but when you do numerical physics, you have to flout best practices when using (old but) robust algorithm (like FFTW). I would love to do it right, but I do not know alternatives compliant with these old libraries (neither as light and as robust new libraries...)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Please, baby steps ! FFTW says I should malloc my arrays... I think I already try hard in terms of good practices :) !

Comment: No. If you allocate memory by `malloc`, it's plainly bad.

Comment: I know, but scientific programming is also about killing baby pandas. Thanks for your help and your time guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using C++11:
You could use a helper struct like :

```
struct voxel_t {
    double val_[2];
    voxel_t() : val_{0.0, 0.0}{};
    explicit voxel_t(bool b): val_{double(b), 0.0}{};
};

template<typename T>
void voxelizator(T* Voxels) {
    // N = total number of voxels, stored in a row-major 1D array
    if (Voxels==NULL) Voxels = new T[N]{} ; // performs below initialization
    //for (int n = 0 ;  n < N ; n++) Voxels[n] = T(0) ;  // no longer needed
    { // Code to voxelizate the space 
        for (int n = 0 ; n<N ; n++) if (is_Matter(n)) Voxels[n] = T{true};
    }
}
```

Sample usage on [ideone](http://ideone.com/4l84do).

This solves the case of double[2] and for bool you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: I love this way of solving the problem, but I'm not using C++11. By the way I could create magic function to cast things correctly, but I will NEVER be able to return a double[2] if I understand things well. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. To return arrays you will need to wrap them up in a struct.

Comment: I would want to give you a "most useful comment" vote to your answer, but I'm a too young padawan to do so ^^.